# Comparing the growth of two functions

Tags: limits, functions

This is my almost final result for comparing two functions.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} =\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{4x}{2x}=2$$
From here can we say which one of these functions grows faster?

Comment: use latex symbol in this view it is not certain for example$\lim\limits_{x\to f(x)} =\frac{4x}{g(x) 2x}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi all i edited my question. could you help me with this?

Comment: do you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} =\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{4x}{2x}$

Comment: yes sir! so could you help me with this question?

Comment: That formula makes no sense.  presumably, the first "=" is a typo, i.e. should read $\lim f/g$ instead of $\lim=f/g$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{4x}{2x}=2\tag1$$
without the "$=$" sign directly after $\lim$.

This reads a bit like a trick question...
The [free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) $x$ in $\dfrac{4x}{2x}$ doesn't relate to the bound variable $x$ in the limit, so you could have written just as well $\dfrac{4z^4}{2z^4}$ or $\dfrac{4\cdot\mathrm{foo}}{2\cdot\mathrm{foo}}$.

Moreover, we just know the limit of the quotient of the two functions as $x\to\infty$, and $f$ and $g$ can be selected from an infinite set.  By no means it's implied that $f(x)=4x$ and $g(x)=2x$. Just to give some examples of functions that match $(1)$:

**Example 1:** Take
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= -4 x^2 \\
g(x) &= -2 x^2
\end{align}$$
and $f$ drops faster than $g$.

**Example 2:** Take
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= 4 + \frac1x\sin(x) \\
g(x) &= 2 - \frac1x\sin(x)
\end{align}$$
$f$ is decreasing each time $g$ is increasing.

**Example 3:** Take
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= -4 \\
g(x) &= -2
\end{align}$$

$f$ and $g$ are not growing / decreasing at all, and $f$ is smaller than $g$.

etc. etc.

Comment: So one scene can cause multiple answer?